# Trace operators on submanifolds

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

In the following paper, *Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds with Bounded Geometry: General Coordinates and Traces*

> https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2539

The authors prove trace theorems for general submanifolds of $M$ using Fermi coordinates. It is mentioned that these trace theorems are used for the classification of boundary value problems for dirac operators on $spin^\mathbb{C}$ manifolds.

I know very little about $spin^\mathbb{C}$ manifolds, or PDEs for that matter. I was wondering whether there are other contexts other in which one would have a need for such a trace theorem. Naively speaking, since trace operators are mainly used to handle boundary conditions, I would think that this could be applied to "boundary value problems" in which the "boundary" is instead a submanifold which is not a hypersurface in $M$.

I have looked all over and seemingly come up with no examples of this, so I am interested in knowing whether or not this is an interesting question. Is it possible and/or interesting to solve even simple PDEs whose "boundary conditions" are on submanifolds? Has this been done before?